# How to create a link to a sub category from a page that is associated with a parent category using MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How would I be able to display a url value from a sub category listed in my MySQL database that looks something like the example below?

```
index.php?cat=category&sub=sub-cat-1&sub2=sub-cat-2&sub3=sub-cat-3
```

Here is the MySQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE categories ( 
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
parentID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
categoryNAME TEXT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
INDEX parent (parentID)
);
```

**UPDATE:**
My end goal is to create a link to a sub category from a page that is associated with a parent category.

Example:
I am on the "Auto Parts"  page and I would like to display a link to the "Engine Parts", "Suspension Parts" and "Transmission Parts" pages.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what it is you want to do?

Comment: its not a good idea to mic case on column names... you should just lowercase everythign and use `_` as a separator, ie. `category_name`, `parent_id` etc..

Comment: @Michael Robinson I want to generate the url using my categories and sub categories from my database.

Comment: I mean update your question to more clearly state what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Michael Robinson How is it not clear i want to display a sub-category from my MySQL database as a link. I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry the question isnt that clear. Do you need help in selecting the correct data? or generating it as a link? What are you trying to achieve? SEF links?

Comment: @Tim Selecting and generating the correct data to display the url.

Comment: @lost-in-SO, I added an update to the question that attempts to give an example.  I hope this accurately indicates what your end goal is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure that a name is unique, at least within its parent. My suggestion for that would be one extra field: `urlName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL`, and one new index: `UNIQUE KEY(parentID, urlName)`. You have to make sure that the `urlName` is safe to put in an url, else you'll get some ugly urls.

That said, your url 'll need some work to. I guess something like this will work:

```
http://example.com/index.php?cat[]=cat&cat[]=subcat1&cat[]=subcat2
```

That'll work, but it's still kinda nasty, I would never use something like that. You should really consider URL Rewriting, so your url will be something like:

```
http://example.com/cat/subcat/subcat2/
```

That's a lot better, isn't it? It's quite easy as well! Just use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Then just explode your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and you're good to go!

Comment: forgive me for my ignorance how would I be able to display the URL using PHP & MySQL? I already now about mod rewrite

Comment: Not really sure what you need.. are you new to PHP/MySQL and need to know about creating the connection and executing a query and returning the results etc?

Comment: Just put it in the url. Couldn't be very hard, is it?

Comment: @Tim yes that would help me out a lot.

Comment: +1 for URL rewriting.  Be patient though, some things are harder depending on your level of experience.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many different ways to do what you want to do and that is up to you to determine the most appropriate way to do it.

Essentially you need to create a connection to the database, run a query to select the data, return it to your page/application so you can output it as part of the link

For the basics on PHP/MySQL I would suggest this tutorial

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

If what your trying to do is part of an overall application where you want database paging or results using querystring parameters there will be a lot more to it than this but if your unsure about just connecting to the database and selecting data etc I would suggest that your not ready to do that just yet, start with the tutorial and go from there

Comment: I know how to connect to the database I'm past that:)